# How to include software in PhpStorm project

Tags: phpstorm, development-environment

I have just started using PhpStorm. In my project I am receiving a lot of undefined variable errors because I am creating a plugin for vBulletin.

I was wondering is there a way to include the main software I am working with in my plugin development, to avoid getting undefined vars, and functions? Kind of how the WordPress plugin development works.

For example I have my projects folder: `c://wamp/www/projects/projectname/` and I have vBulletin in `c://wamp/www/vb3/`

I want to be able to tell PhpStorm "hey the core scripts to this project are here".

Comment: **PHP Include paths**: 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/php.html#include-path-tab 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-include-paths.html  or you can do that with **Additional Content Root** (will be displayed as a separate node in the project view / treated as a separate folder that is part of the project itself): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-content-roots.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As LazyOne said I was able to achieve this using include paths.

> Include paths are used for holding third-party code that is used for completion and reference resolution in some functions/methods that use file paths as arguments, for example, require() or include().
>
> Note that the files added via include paths are not meant to be edited within the scope of your project. If you have the existing code that you need to access and modify from within several projects, consider adding it via an additional content root.

1. Do one of the following:

   - To configure the include paths for the current project, in the
     Settings/Preferences dialog Ctrl+Alt+S, click PHP under Languages &
     Frameworks.
   - To configure the include paths that will be applied to all newly
     created projects, use the default new project settings (File | New
     Projects Settings | Settings for New Projects ).
2. On the PHP page that opens, configure the list of include paths on the Include path tab:

   - Use Add and Remove to add and remove paths.
   - Use Move up and Move down to reorder the items in the list.
   - Click the Sort Alphabetically button to sort the paths alphabetically in the ascending order.